# Can't import certificate into Exchange 2013: Private Key Missing (I know it's there.)

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, exchange, ssl-certificate, openssl, exchange-2013

I know this question has been asked before and I've gone through countless threads on here (as well as google) trying all of them. Unfortunately, I think I'm having an unrelated issue to what others have had.

I have a CRT and KEY file on our CentOS webserver. It's working fine. We want to use it on our Windows 2008 R2 Standard server for Exchange 2013.

I have verified my keyfile checks out:

```
# openssl rsa -text -in mydomain.key
Private-Key: (4096 bit)
```

I have attempted to convert it into a PFX:

```
# openssl pkcs12 -export -out mydomain.pfx -inkey mydomain.key -in mydomain.crt
```

After converting, I can even test the PFX file to make sure it does contain a private key:

```
# openssl pkcs12 -in exchange.pfx  -nodes
Enter Import Password:
MAC verified OK
Bag Attributes
    localKeyID: 63 04 21 C5 D8 02 0E E2 A9 A7 6E E4 CD 90 66 1E 27 95 8F 0D 
    friendlyName: My Company SSL
subject=/OU=Domain Control Validated/CN=*.mydomain.tld
issuer=/C=BE/O=GlobalSign nv-sa/CN=AlphaSSL CA - SHA256 - G2
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
(Redacted, obviously.)
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
Bag Attributes
    localKeyID: 63 04 21 C5 D8 02 0E E2 A9 A7 6E E4 CD 90 66 1E 27 95 8F 0D 
    friendlyName: My Company SSL
Key Attributes: <No Attributes>
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
(Redacted, obviously.)
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Exchange allows me to import it, but then it never shows in the ECP. When I try to remove the key through the Exchange Console, this is the error I get:

```
[PS] C:\Windows\system32>remove-exchangecertificate

cmdlet Remove-ExchangeCertificate at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Thumbprint: 630421C5D8020EE2A9A76EE4CD90661E27958F0D

Confirm
Are you sure you want to perform this action?
Remove certificate with thumbprint 630421C5D8020EE2A9A76EE4CD90661E27958F0D from the computer's certificate store?
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [?] Help (default is "Y"): Y
A special Rpc error occurs on server TWEXCHANGE: The certificate with thumbprint
630421C5D8020EE2A9A76EE4CD90661E27958F0D was found but is not valid for use with Exchange Server (reason:
PrivateKeyMissing).
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Remove-ExchangeCertificate], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : [Server=TWEXCHANGE,RequestId=75aa9cfb-6db4-4c0d-aae3-5eaa32eb0389,TimeStamp=3/25/2015 9:
   24:49 PM] [FailureCategory=Cmdlet-InvalidOperationException] DE2A4BCA,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.SystemConfigur
  ationTasks.RemoveExchangeCertificate
    + PSComputerName        : twexchange.mydomain.com
```

The only way to remove it is to open the MMC, add the Certificate Snap-In and connect to Computer Certificates. I can search by the SHA1 thumbprint and delete it. (If I don't delete it, when I attempt to import it again, I get an error that the thumbprint already exists.)

I've also attempted to convert my PEM key/crt file to DER and import that way:

```
# openssl x509 -outform der -in mydomain.pem -out mydomain.cer
```

I have the exact same results in Exchange 2013, it silently imports it, won't display it on the ECP and when I check it in the MMC: it's missing the private key. Any help at this point would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried importing the certificate using the MMC Certificate snap-in?

Comment: Using MMC: When I attempt to import the DER certificate (*.cer file) it does not import the private key. When I import the PFX certificate it DOES import and shows a little key icon, representing (I believe) that the private key was properly imported as well.

Unfortunately, it doesn't show up on the Exchange Control Panel (ECP) when I hit refresh... where to go from here?

Comment: Doh! I just used the Exchange Console to do it manually and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes certificate import via Exchange (ECP or EMS) just doesn't work; if you are sure your certificate is ok, try importing it via the MMC "Certificates" snap-in; make sure to import the certificate in the "Personal" store of the computer (not the user).

After the certificate is imported, Exchange will recognize it and you will be able to enable it for Exchange services.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the solution is to getting this to import through Exchange, but Massimo found a work around. If the PFX is imported through MMC > Certificates > Computer, it allowed me to add it via the Exchange Console.

Comment: I'm posting this as an answer, then; feel free to accept it :)